# Как удалить из трея Linux Mint 12 значок "Настройки клавиатуры"?

Tags: linux, linux-mint, ubuntu

У меня 2 вопроса, близких по содержанию.

1. Как удалить из трея Linux Mint 12 значок "Настройки клавиатуры"? Всё равно не нужный значок.
2. Как удалить из трея Linux Mint 12 значок "Раскладка клавиатуры". Ненужный, потому что есть X Neural.

Answer (score 1):

В сведениях посмотрите названия обоих аплетов (ПКМ-на апплте), потом удаляйте как вам удобнее, терминал или менеджер приложений.